# How long can you wait/hang out at the Oakland airport lobby?

Tags: airports, oak

I have an early morning flight at 6:00 am from OAK (Oakland airport). The public transport doesn't get there early enough in the morning so I'm planning to take it the night before and arrive around midnight.

Is it okay to just chill in the lobby for a few hours? (I'm pretty sure you can't check in that early) Will probably just read or something (not going to sleep).

Is this allowed?

Comment: It's fine, and many airlines allow early check in (6 hrs) I have also seen airlines that allow check ins as early as 12 hrs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri and http://www.sleepinginairports.net/

Comment: How well can you hide? ;)

Comment: Monday through Friday, public transportation (the new train connected to BART) arrives before 5:00 a.m. No joy on weekends though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Oakland International Airport's FAQ](http://www.oaklandairport.com/faqs.aspx):

> **May I remain overnight in the terminals?**
>
> Connecting passengers with an overnight layover may remain overnight in the terminals pre-security only. Since we are open 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, law enforcement officers are always on site and you may be asked to show your identification and proof of travel.
>
> If you decide to you want a little more comfort than an airport can provide, and want to stay in a near-by hotel rather than remaining in the terminals, Oakland International Airport suggests you stay at one that has a complimentary airport shuttle available in the early morning hours. The closest hotels are on either Airport Access Road or Hegenberger Road, or read "Airport Area". You may find the list of area hotels on our website at: [visitoakland.org](http://visitoakland.org/visiting_accommodations.cfm)